# Well definedness of the limit function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

I have a silly question on the well-definedness of functions, which arose when I revisited the case for integrals: Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable, and define $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \to \int_0^x f(y)\ dy$. **Why is this actually well defined?** Since this case is analogous to a simpler case, I would like to regard the simpler version. Suppose $A$ is a set of real valued sequences that converge. Then one can define $$f:A \to \mathbb{R}, \ (a_n)_n \mapsto \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n.$$ What I wanted to explain to myself was why this function is well defined, taking nothing for granted.

When trying to think about well definedness, I always go back to the set-theoretic definition of a function. In this case it should be $$f=\{x \ | \exists y \in A,z \in \mathbb{R}: x=(y,z) \ \wedge \ z=\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n\}.$$ To check this is a function I need to check that $(a,b),(a,c) \in f \implies b = c.$ But by definition of $f$ we have $b=\lim a_n$ and $c=\lim a_n$, so this follows by equality axioms. Again by the equality axioms, one should always get a function whenever the $2$nd component of the tuple is defined by an equality as above. Hence the issue here lies a bit "deeper". I suppose that when introducing a symbol that depends on previous objects, such as the limit of a sequence depending on the sequence, one needs to make sure that this is unique, because otherwise one would introduce one symbol for an ambiguous object. More precisely: It theoretically could have been the case that the limit is not unique. If one would then introduce a symbol $\lim a_n$ despite that, this could denote any of those objects, hence being ambiguous and violating the equality axioms. So what is "going on" here, is that the function is essentially well defined because we introduced a symbol for a unique object and defined the function building on that. In other words, the takeaway should be that one can only define new symbols that use previous objects in the notation, if the new object is unique. This would then also hold for the integral case above. I'd appreciate some feedback whether my understanding is correct.

Comment: The well-definedness of $F$ is essentially the condition that the integrand is integrable!

Comment: The symbol $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ doesn't refer to anything unless the limit exists, and if the limit exists it is unique; that is, you can show, from the definition of the limit, that if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are two values satisfying that definition then $L_1 = L_2$. That's what justifies thinking of "limit" as a function.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I understand what you are saying, however I am not sure whether you are agreeing with my attempted explanation or not. Could you elaborate on that a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I'm agreeing. We prove that the limit is a well-defined real number and similarly for the integral.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks again! Just to be sure that I am correct on this, you also agree that this is essentially inherited by the fact that we can only introduce a new symbol that depends on previously introduced objects, if it is unique? If you answer this you might as well want to consider turning your comments into an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Well, I'm not prepared to say something that general; people do consider multi-valued functions in various contexts. It is true that $\lim$ and $\int_a^b$ are literally functions and accordingly have single-valued outputs. But, for example, the indefinite integral $\int$ is not unique but only unique up to a constant so strictly speaking it does not define a function from functions to functions.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see, but if one would be able to introduce "f(x)" as a symbol to refer to an according object of a multivalued function, I could have two different objects that are denoted by $f(x)$, violating that $f(x)=f(x)$, or am I getting something wrong here? This is why I thought one needs uniqueness to introduce such kinds of symbols. But then again, I don't know.

Comment: This is what people *should* do but I'm not prepared to claim that it always actually happens.